# How does MPLS header give information about the next protocol?

Tags: networking, network-programming, vpn

How does MPLS header give information about the next protocol ?

I did some research on internet , and found that the router holds that information, since router is the one assigning the labels.

But there must be some information about next protocol passed on at every label switching which can be extracted when packet goes out of mpls domain.

Comment: The MPLS header does not have any information about the next protocol. In MPLS domain there is some label distribution protocol such as RSVP-TE or CR-LDP. The egress router knows which ether type the packet have. This information is synced with egress router using any of those protocols. Egress router check the tag and set corresponding type.

Answer (score 0):

Typically MPLS header would not hold any information about the next protocol.
It will hold the information, whether to expect one more MPLS header or not.

It is bottom-of-stack bit, to indicate one more label. 
Else the data is popped out of MPLS headers and given to next level engine to Handle (it will typically contain a L2 or L3/IP header), it is done while the programming that correct engine is associated.

Answer (score 0):

MPLS header will contain Labels. It does not contain any information about next protocols. Ingress router adds MPLS header and Egress router removes MPLS header. When the packet reached Egress router, MPLS header will be removed and it acts like normal Layer2/3 packet which performs routing. 
On label switching only the labels got swapped. No extra informations will be added/deleted.